# Has anyone used IntelliJ for a client side markdown editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

Has anyone used IntelliJ for a client side markdown editor?

I use IntelliJ IDEA for my programming but would like to use it for editing my markdown files, has anyone tried this?

Comment: Yes, I did. What's your real question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Markdown plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=5970) that seems to be what you are looking for, is this what you need?

Edit: plugin is now discontinued, [here's another one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793)

Comment: link does not work can you update